# Contar elementos seleccionados de un select box con javascript

Tags: javascript, django

Saludos, tengo un select box (id_encuentros) y necesito saber cuantos elementos se han seleccionado para restrigirlo, es decir si ha seleccionado más de una opción entonces le mostraría un mensaje de alerta.

Alguien sabe como hacerlo en javascript o jquery?

Gracias.

Comment: Agregar algún código que tengas sería de mucha utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final encontré la solución, por si a alguien le vale:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var count = $("#id_acciones :selected").length;
    if(count>1) {
        alert("Solo puede seleccionar un curso")
    }
}
</script>
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Faltaría un poco de código de tu parte para poner algo más concreto, pero con jQuery se puede con algo así:

```
$(':checked').size()
```

Fijate de restringir los los elementos por input, por nombre, por algún tipo de atributo, etc.

Referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp